# Xamarin select only one radio button

Tags: xamarin

i Am trying to create a survey form dynamically.Below is my code in view model.
I am adding the data to a grid and then to a stack layout.

```
    foreach (var item in Settings.VOCQuestionDetailsSettings.RespondantQuestionnare)

         {

            myGrid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.Questions, TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold }, 0, rowCount);
            rowCount++;
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Choices.Count; i++)
            {
                if (item.QuestionType == "Radio")
                {
                    myGrid.Children.Add(new CustomRadioButton
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        Text = item.Choices[i],
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        FontSize = 14,
                    }, 0, rowCount);
                    rowCount++;
                }
}
}
```

IF The question type is radio i am displaying the radio buttons.However now i need to disable other radio options if i select one.

Comment: Do you mean you allow the user to choose only once?

Comment: No, item.Choices has number of choices from which the user can select must he must be able to select only one per question.

Comment: Unclear what CustomRadioButton is, but usually Radio items would go into a RadioGroup, which would ensure only one button can be selected at a time.

Comment: Since xamarin does not have a radio button i have used a custom renderer to create one.Customradiobutton is the button from that renderer